# GXT Shortcut Icon Alignment

Tags: alignment, gxt

I am trying to align my shortcut icon in the center.  However, I have not found a way to do it yet.  Below is my code:

```
    Shortcut sh = new Shortcut();
    sh.setSize(String.valueOf(BUTTON_SIZE), String.valueOf(BUTTON_SIZE));
    sh.setText("Shortcut Name");
    sh.setIcon(ICONS.desktop());
    sh.setIconStyle("bottomPanelShortcut");  // (1) this does not work.
    mLeftToolbar.add(sh);
```

.bottomPanelShortcut {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

The issue is that without the (1) statement, it shows the desktop image, but not centered.
If I include the (1) statement, then the image disappears.

Thank you for help!

Peter